# what is difference between find() and children() in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I got Question in interview. What is main difference between **find()** and **children()**.
Please answer .
Thanks in advance

Comment: just check jQuery docs

Comment: Please check the documentation of jQuery

Comment: RTFM: http://api.jquery.com/children + http://api.jquery.com/find

Comment: You didn't show any effort.

Answer (score 2):

Find method is used to **find all levels down the DOM tree** but **children find single level down the DOM tree**.